# Images.xcassets: error: Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode9-beta, ios11, xcode8

When I tried to run the app in simulators, I hold Xcode 8.3.2 and Xcode 9 beta 1 and my project was running in Xcode 8.3.2. I got the below errors.

```
Images.xcassets: error: Failed to find a suitable device for the type SimDeviceType : com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x with runtime SimRuntime : 10.3 (14E269) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-10-3
    Failure Reason: Failed to create SimDeviceSet at path /Users/Mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices. You'll want to check the logs in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator to see why creating the SimDeviceSet failed.
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: Failed to initialize simulator device set.
        Failure Reason: Failed to subscribe to notifications from CoreSimulatorService.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: Error returned in reply to notification request: Connection invalid
            Failure Reason: Software caused connection abort
/* com.apple.actool.document.notices */
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on Xcode 8.3.3 - did you find any working solution for this issue?

Comment: @AkashThakkar as of now I didn't get any solution for this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For me it did not help cleaning. I had to run `sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService` and then I was able to start the app via the Simulator

Comment: Thank you! Cleaning the project wasn't enough for me... I had to run the command you recommended :)

Comment: Cleaning was not enough for me either.  I must have had other issues.  Restarted my mac, cleaned my build folder and it worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

I had this error and solved it by just opening Simulator from the Xcode menu.

`Xcode` -> `Open Developer Tool` -> `Simulator`

Once the simulator was open and finished booting, I cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Comment: I had this too, turned out I had the Xcode 8 simulator open in the background while using Xcode 9.2... Closing it and opening the correct one fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try and Clean the Project and then Run thats what I did

Goto Product > Clean, then run